# Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'keyboardDidShowNotification'

Tags: ios, keyboard-events, nsnotificationcenter, swift4.2

I'm getting this error with Swift 4.2

> Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'keyboardDidShowNotification'

Here is my code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Following one was working fine with Swift 4 but not with Swift 4.2

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
```

[image]

Apple document Ref: [NSNotification.Name.keyboardDidShowNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621602-keyboarddidshownotification)

Comment: As with your "button type" question... @Krunal - this may be helpful... (not mine, and I haven't tried it... just found via search): https://gist.github.com/benasher44/de0a75a4583e5f57853998142e795776

Comment: @DonMag - Thank you for it. It's very nice. But loosk like a patch/support for Swift4.2. I'm migrating my complete project.

Comment: Sure... but that gist *could* be a decent reference for these types of syntax changes. As far as migrating the complete project, Xcode 10 *does* have a Migration Assistant that may help. Ref: https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift4.2/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I believe you use it like this now.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, 
    selector: #selector(self.keyboardDidShow(notification:)), 
    name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil) 

/* You can substitute UIResponder with any of it's subclass */
```

It is listed in `UIResponder` [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder?changes=latest_minor) as a *Type Property*.

Comment: Odd that `.keyboardDidShowNotification` is found in both `UIWindow` and `UIResponder`.

Comment: @rmaddy i actually got this as a suggestion from xcode. But when i go to the docs to the page of the notification, it shows up under `UIWindow`. :/

Comment: Oddly, both versions (UIWindow and UIResponder) compile.

Comment: @rmaddy i found out why i think. _"Many key objects are also responders, including the UIApplication object, UIViewController objects, and all UIView objects (which **includes UIWindow**)"_ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder

Comment: `.keyboardDidShowNotification` must actually be declared in `UIResponder` because I can do `UIView.keyboardDidShowNotification` or any class that ultimately descends from `UIResponder`.

Comment: i am really confused why observer UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification not getting called . I am using it inside  KeyboardViewController of keyboard Extension.

Answer (score 5):

Working on swift 4,2

```
 func bindToKeyboard(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(UIView.keyboardWillChange(_:)), name:
        UIApplication.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification
        , object: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have used just the `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` except using `NSNotification.Name.` . This is working in **SWIFT 5**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(KeyboardLayoutConstraint.keyboardWillShowNotification(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHideNotification(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

When I command-click on keyboardWillShowNotification and select jump to definition.

```
extension UIResponder {

    
    public class let keyboardWillShowNotification: NSNotification.Name

    public class let keyboardDidShowNotification: NSNotification.Name

    public class let keyboardWillHideNotification: NSNotification.Name

    public class let keyboardDidHideNotification: NSNotification.Name

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some small details added to this answer:

```
func setupViews(){
            // Keyboard notification observers
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil) 
    }


    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After update in Swift 4.2 you directly use `.UIKeyboardDidShow` and `.UIKeyboardDidHide`

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
```

Comment: Looks like this might cause issues? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50915736/2227743

Answer (score -3):

@Krunal.... remove 'NSNotification.Name' it will be working

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55980922/2227743).