# I want to change my view's frame when the keyboard shows

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

Here is my function for adding an observer

```
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

but `.UIKeyboardWillShow` is giving me an error

> 'UIKeyboardWillShow' has been renamed to
>   'UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification'
>
> Replace 'UIKeyboardWillShow' with
>   'UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification'

but when I replace it

```
func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
}
```

I get this error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: You need to remove the `.` before `UIResponder`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316676/type-nsnotification-name-has-no-member-keyboarddidshownotification/52325564#52325564

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type 'NSNotification.Name' has no member 'keyboardDidShowNotification'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52316676/type-nsnotification-name-has-no-member-keyboarddidshownotification)

Comment: And you need to import UIKit module not Foundation

Answer (score 5):

Without a dot

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), 
name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: Second solution won't work I guess (`Type 'NSNotification.Name?' has no member 'keyboardWillShowNotification'`).

Comment: @AndréSlotta actually not tried it but op will give feedback

Comment: It works but the or part doesn't thanks a lot anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                self.keyboardWillShow(notification: notification)
            }
notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
                self.keyboardWillHide(notification: notification)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import module `UIKit` because `UIResponder` is part of `UIKit` not `Foundation` module

> SWIFT 5 CODE

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addObservers()
    }

    public func addObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleKeyboardWillShow(_: Notification) {
        // Here handle keyboard
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this, and working perfectly fine

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShowOrHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil);
```

Comment: It doesn't in Swift 4.2